# install Ubuntu in Pen Drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive

Can we install Ubuntu in a pen Drive? Actually, Currently, i am using window system and running shortage of space. So, i planned for installing ubuntu in my USB pen drive. But, At the time of space allocation, it didn't recognize the drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Depending on what type of USB install you want. Persistent (saving changes) or non persistent (just like a live Ubuntu CD). For more information [read this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux/).

For a persistent install guide [try this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/usb-ubuntu-904-persistent-install-windows/). (Example for Jaunty Jackalope)

For a non-persistent install guide [try this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/usb-ubuntu-804-installation-from-windows/). (Example for Hardy Heron)

If you have tried to install Ubuntu with the above guides and failed, then your USB stick may be the problem. To run an OS off a USB it needs to have good read/write speeds.

Can you elaborate on: *But, At the time of space allocation, it didn't recognize the drive.*